# Javascript/bookmarklet not doing the same thing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

```
document.getElementById('channel_actions').innerHTML =     document.getElementById('channel_actions').innerHTML + '<button id = "toggleButton" style =     "position: absolute;height:32px;margin-left:0px" onclick = "toggleOverlay();">Start Overlay</button>';
```

How come when I do this in my chrome console it adds on to the page like expected but when I make it a bookmarklet this is the only thing it shows. It almost seems like the bookmarklet is calling document.write(My code) or something. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you prefacing the bookmarklet with `javascript:`?

Comment: Please post the entire code of your bookmarklet; it will make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The old way: `javascript:/*your code*/; void(0);`

Best practice: `javacript:(function(){ /*your code*/   })();`

Comment: Yes I am using the best practice way. But why is it giving me different results when i use a proper bookmarklet vrs inputing it directly into google chrome?

Comment: Then you need to be more clear next time and show that. You waste people's time.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. for some reason i need to make a function start and instead of making the button pop up i use set timeout(start,100) and it worked.